# trouble using react-bootstrap for grid layout

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

First off, my FE skills are pretty basic so sorry upfront if this a silly question...

I'm trying to create a basic blog page and I'm having trouble with the layout of the content div and the post links div. I want them to be kinda float side by side so that they have a margin from each other, the sides and the header/footer.

I'm using react-bootstrap for that and it sort of works but what I can't figure out why the content div has no margin from the top and the sidebar div does..

here is my site: https://tal-joffe.github.io/blog
(ignore the ugly colors and fonts I just started :) )

this is the component that contains both divs:

```
const PostsTab = () => (
    <div className="post-tab">
        <Grid>
            <Row>
                <Col md={8}>
                    <ContentContainer/>
                </Col>
                <Col md={4}>
                    <VisiblePostsList/>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Grid>
    </div>
)
```

And this is the css I have for the inner components on the containers and the body:

```
.side-bar {
  background-color: gray;
  min-height: 800px;
}
.post-content{
  background-color: #efefef;
  min-height: 800px;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

There is no other global css code and I don't use any inline styles in the javascript code.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why should they have a "margin-top"?

Comment: @Andrew I just think it looks better. regardless I'm trying to improve my frontend capabilities and wanted to understand why would the 2 divs act differently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no margin on either column. Browsers give HTML heading tags margins. In your case, the sidebar's `h2` tag is the reason the sidebar looks like it has a margin on the top. Try styling the `h2` with `margin-top: 0;`

You should add a margin-top style to `.row` or `.container`. Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks that was exactly the issue. I didn't know tags inside the div could have an impact...